# ASP MVC 5: write a real & on html file instead of &amp;

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a `Html.DropDownListFor` that should get fontawesome from the database

here is the code

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HomePage_Head_Tab1_ICON, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @{List<SelectListItem> DropdownItemList =
                        DataAccessLayer.ConfigurationManagementAccess.GetListofFontAwesomeStrings();  }

                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.HomePage_Head_Tab1_ICON, DropdownItemList, Model.HomePage_Head_Tab1_ICON, new { @class = "fa form-control", @style= "\"font-family: 'FontAwesome',Arial;\"" ,@id="selectamp"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HomePage_Head_Tab1_ICON, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

but the output becomes

```
<option value="fa-500px">&amp;#xf26e;</option>
```

it should be

```
<option value="fa-500px">&#xf26e;</option>
```

so that the fontawesome will display properly

please help me, i've been searching for 3 hours now and nothing works for far,
I even wrote a Jquery that replaces  `&amp;` with `&` but it still produces &

`why you do this to me asp?`

Comment: Why do you think you want to do this?

Comment: I wanted to display fontawesome inside the select. the fontawesome strings comes from the database, and when razor displays the ampersand, it writes &amp; instead of & so it does not show properly

Answer (score 0):

This is an *HTML encoding* issue.

If you want to display the value as-is without any HTML encoding you should use the `Html.Raw` helper:

```
@Html.Raw(Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.HomePage_Head_Tab1_ICON, DropdownItemList, Model.HomePage_Head_Tab1_ICON, new { @class = "fa form-control", @style= "\"font-family: 'FontAwesome',Arial;\"" ,@id="selectamp"}))
```

Comment: I have tried this but i received an error:
Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.IHtmlString' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Editted my answer, try like this.